# How to debug a bash script in a qemu-arm chroot

Tags: qemu, arm, debugging, strace

I'm running a debian debootstrap script which creates an arm system. However, the script fails at some point and the error message does not really help. So I'll have to do some more debugging which is more complicated than I thought. The script is already running with set -x, maximum verbosity, etc. So I guess strace is my only option left. But strace (with -ff option) only gives an output until the chroot step starts. I don't know what exactly is the reason for this. The chroot step itself (because strace can't look into the chroot) or that it is running under arm in the chroot (which it shouldn't because it is started outside the chroot)? If I start strace in the chroot it also does not work because there seems to be only a very limited support by qemu. So the best would be to run strace on my normal system but it must have the ability to look inside the chroot. But I'm not sure if that is possible. Maybe someone knows also some other advanced debugging options beyond strace?

Answer (score 0):

I ran

```
strace -o /var/tmp/chr.1 -f chroot . /bin/bash
```

I found I was missing a copy of qemu-arm in the /usr/bin/ of the chroot dir.